# Using Google Cloud Pub/Sub from Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-pubsub

In my current project we are already using Google Pub/Sub: cloud.google.com/Pub_Sub‎

Now, we also need to create a Chrome extension, which will be sending some information for each url (of a specific domain). Extension does not need to receive anything. I was wondering if pub/sub is a good idea for this? (is it even possible?) Or should I create a web-service for this.

If it is possible, could someone please point me to any existing application, which does it?

I am new to pub/sub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual publishing probably shouldn't be done through the extension. This is because you'll need to distribute the app and you can't include the credentials you need for authenticating to Cloud Pub/Sub.

Instead, you should create a separate service, perhaps a serverless setup using [Cloud Run](http://cloud.google.com/run) or [Cloud Functions](http://cloud.google.com/functions) that handle requests from the chrome extension and deals with authentication automatically. Those functions can then publish to Cloud Pub/Sub.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,.. 
If I have to publish via extension, how can I do that? 
I mean I expect users to install extension via chrome extension store. So they need not do anything else (like installing Node.js etc), but still extension should be able to publish stuff to the specified topic. is that possible? If so, how? (is their any example anywhere?)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's a good way to do so. The main reason is that Cloud Pub/Sub (and many other cloud services), don't allow unauthenticated requests. Otherwise, anyone can essentially use your account to do malicious things and possibly rack up a huge bill for you at the end of the month. You also can't authenticate the traditional way since that includes putting your authentication credentials inside the extension's code, which leaves your account vulnerable to malicious third parties.

Comment: OK, do you know of any bad way to do it?